# How can I check a element by class name which has some classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if there is a element which has some class names or not

Example

```
<div id="text1" class="myclass searchA searchB searchC">...</div>
<div id="text2" class="myclass searchB searchA searchC">...</div>
<div id="text3" class="myclass searchD searchB searchA">...</div>
<div id="text3" class="myclass searchX searchY searchZ">...</div>
```

I tried to do it with this, but it wont work

```
var lookfor =".searchA.searchB";
console.log('id from div how matched the loorfor classes:'+$(".myclass").is(lookfor).attr('id'));
```

I also tried this

```
console.log('id from div how matched the loorfor classes:'+$(".myclass").hasClass(lookfor).attr('id'));
```

Additional notes: the order of the classes that I'm looking for can be different each time. Also it's important to check if all classes in the element are only one.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Is it possible to limit the search for a div? Example

```
<div id="firstdiv">
 <div id="text1_first" class="myclass searchA searchB searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text2_first" class="myclass searchB searchA searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text3_first" class="myclass searchD searchB searchA">...</div>
    <div id="text3_first" class="myclass searchX searchY searchZ">...</div>
</div>
<div id="scnddiv">
 <div id="text1_scnd" class="myclass searchA searchB searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text2_scnd" class="myclass searchB searchA searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text3_scnd" class="myclass searchD searchB searchA">...</div>
    <div id="text3_scnd" class="myclass searchX searchY searchZ">...</div>
</div>
```

Now I want only the classes inside the `scnd` div that matched my `lookfor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a filter, just use the selector directly:

```js
const id = $(".myclass.searchA.searchB").attr('id');
console.log('id from div which matched the classes: ' + id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text1" class="myclass searchA searchB searchC">...</div>
<div id="text2" class="myclass searchB searchA searchC">...</div>
<div id="text3" class="myclass searchD searchB searchA">...</div>
<div id="text3" class="myclass searchX searchY searchZ">...</div>
```

### Update

To the update of your question:

```js
const id1 = $("#firstdiv .myclass.searchA.searchB").attr('id');
console.log('ID from the firstdiv that matched the classes: ' + id1);

const id2 = $("#scnddiv .myclass.searchA.searchB").attr('id');
console.log('ID from scnddiv that matched the classes: ' + id2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="firstdiv">
    <div id="text1_first" class="myclass searchA searchB searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text2_first" class="myclass searchB searchA searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text3_first" class="myclass searchD searchB searchA">...</div>
    <div id="text3_first" class="myclass searchX searchY searchZ">...</div>
</div>

<div id="scnddiv">
    <div id="text1_scnd" class="myclass searchA searchB searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text2_scnd" class="myclass searchB searchA searchC">...</div>
    <div id="text3_scnd" class="myclass searchD searchB searchA">...</div>
    <div id="text3_scnd" class="myclass searchX searchY searchZ">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, it looks much more easier. What will happend if the classes matched more than one div? Is it possible to limit the search for classes inside another div , i will update my question for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what i want to learn ;-)